# Determine the largest 3-digit prime factor of the integer $\binom{2000}{1000}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Determine the largest 3-digit prime factor of the integer 
 $\binom{2000}{1000}$?

Here $\binom{2000}{1000}$ is the combination $\binom{n}{r}$ where $n=2000$ ,$r=1000$.

This is a problem from the RMO -- Regional Math Olympiad (India) 1992.

Comment: Do you know a formula for $_nC_r$?

Comment: What is the RMO?

Comment: @6005. Regional math Olympiad. (India)

Comment: @Shailesh Cool! Good to know.

Comment: @Shailesh  is it like qualifications for IMO ?

Comment: @A---B Yes, it is the first stage. The students who clear the RMO, appear for the INMO (Indian National Mathematics Olympiad). Then there is a training camp, from which the best students are selected.

Comment: @A---B yes, kind of. Then you do INMO (Indian) and then IMO (international)

Comment: And, I think the original question was a little different. It wanted the largest 3 digit prime factor.

Comment: @Anonymous_original You gave that exam ? Maybe adding the year will helpful for future readers.

Comment: @A---B I didn't give the exam in the year in which this question was asked. And the paper for the RMO is different for different regions. The regional coordinators can set their own question papers. I have seen this question in a problem book(that contains problems from Olympiads).

Comment: @Anonymous_original: the largest 3 digit prime factor is considerably harder than finding the largest.

Comment: @miracle173 Yes, it is a olympiad question. The question about finding the largest prime factor is more a computational problem. It is too easy to be an olympiad problem.

Comment: i tied it now and saw it is a little bit harder :-)

Comment: @A---B Yeah, I got it. The question about finding the largest 3 digit prime factor was question 3 of the RMO which was held in 1992.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

- Any prime $p$ dividing $\binom{2000}{1000}$ divides $2000!$. (Why?)
- Conversely, any prime $p$ dividing $2000!$, **that is between $1000$ and $2000$**, divides $\binom{2000}{1000}$. (Why?)

So what will the answer be?

Answer (score 0):

$${2000!\over1000! * 1000!} = {2000 * 1999 * \dots *1001 \over 1000!} = \text{Some Integer}$$

So you need to find highest prime between $1000- 2000$.

Answer:

> 1999.